# count increasing groups for given array

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array integers

pick items into groups such that the group hold unique integers, also the group holds the numbers in increasing sequence without any missing integer in between.

Valid groups are: `(1,2,3), (5,6,7)`
Invalid groups are: `(1,3,4)` because `2` is missing here.

**Example case:**

```
input array = 13, 11, 4, 12, 5, 4

Result is 11
```

**Explanation:**

```
Groups of size 1 are [13],[11],[4],[12],[5],[4], we have 6 groups

Groups of size 2 are [12,13], [11,12], [4,5], [4,5], we have 4 groups, here [4,5] is repeated twice as we have 2 occurrences of 4

Groups of size 3 are [11,12,13], we have 1 group

Groups of size 4 is 0

Total groups are 6 + 4 + 1 = 11
```

Here is my code:

my idea is to group elements which are next to each other then find the possible count using formula `n * (n-1)/2`

```
public static long solve(List<Integer> list) {
    Collections.sort(list);

    List<List<Integer>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    // logic to build group of items like [[4,4,5],[11,12,13]]
    // buildGroups(groups, list);
    // removed grouping logic to concentrate on issue.

    long result = list.size();
    for(List<Integer> e : groups) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(e);
        int m = set.size();
        int formula = m * (m-1)/2;
        result += formula; // Using formula to get count
        if(m != e.size()) {
            result += m-1; // we have duplicates so get count for them
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If a duplicate occurs at starting or ending point of a group then my formula result += m-1 works.

But it fails if a group holds duplicate values that are not at starting or ending, for example `[3,4,4,5,6]` or multiple occurrences of duplicates at any positions like `[3,4,4,4,4,5]`

So here is a sample test case for which my code fails:

**Input:**

```
[3,4,4,5,6]
```

**Combinations:**

```
[3],[4],[4],[5],[6]
[3,4], [3,4], [4,5], [4,5], [5,6]
[3,4,5], [3,4,5], [4,5,6], [4,5,6]
[3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6]
Total possibilities are 5 + 5 + 4 + 2
Result = 16
```

What is the correct approach to solve this problem.

Comment: @WJS, I have not added any links in this post.

Comment: Mea Culpa and my apologies.   Apparently I saw the challenge link in another post and posted the comment to this one.  I have no idea how I did that.

Comment: learner, I deleted my brain-dead question.

Comment: learner, your comment led me to investigate my code more carefully. In doing so I discovered a fatal flaw that I should have found earlier. That's why I deleted my answer. I will investigate whether I can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the frequency of each value in a `TreeMap`, then iterate over it while keeping track of the number of groups with consecutive elements up to the current element.

```java
public static long solve(List<Integer> list) {
    var freq = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1, Integer::sum, TreeMap::new));
    long ans = 0, curr = 0;
    int prev = 0;
    for (var entry : freq.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() == prev + 1) curr = (curr + 1) * entry.getValue();
        else curr = entry.getValue();
        ans += curr;
        prev = entry.getKey();
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain how this logic can solve this problem.

Comment: @learner We find the frequency of each element, then we iterate over the distinct elements in order. At each point, we keep a count of how many groups of consecutive elements end at the current element. If the current element is one more than the previous element, then the groups ending at this point can include any of the groups ending at the previous element concatenated with the current element, or just the current element on its own.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are doing, mainly because I don't know Java. In particular I don't follow how you are handling duplicates.

Comment: @CarySwoveland First, the frequency of each element is stored in a TreeMap (which is a sorted map). Then, we keep track of the number of groups ending at the current element while iterating over the map.

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are already very good, but we can do better than O(n log n).

By using a hash map and a bit of "combinatorics", we can achieve expected O(n).

> my idea is to group elements which are next to each other then find the possible count

That's actually a good approach! Let's first count the frequency of each element using a hash map.

```java
var freq = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (var i : ints)
    freq.put(i, freq.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
```

(you can also write this in a functional style like Unmitigated)

Now, let's group the numbers into groups of consecutive numbers. We will also update the count of subsequences inside these groups as we process groups. Let's keep track of the numbers we have already grouped in a hash set. We iterate over the numbers we haven't grouped yet.

```java
long count = 0;
var grouped = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (var entry : freq.entrySet()) {
    if (grouped.contains(entry.getKey()))
        continue;
```

We find the extent of a group by going left & right as far as possible, starting from any element inside the group:

```java
int min = entry.getKey();
while (freq.containsKey(min - 1))
    min--;
int max = entry.getKey();
while (freq.containsKey(max + 1))
    max++;
```

Now we have to count the number of subsequences inside the group. We can do this in linear time in the size of the group. We also mark all numbers in the group as "grouped" so that we don't process the same group again (which would both be incorrect and ruin the runtime).

```java
long subseqs = 0; // number of subsequences up to but excluding i
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    grouped.add(i);
    // We can append any of the duplicate elements...
    subseqs *= freq.get(i);
    // Or we can just start a new subsequence with any of the duplicate elements.
    subseqs += freq.get(i);
    // We can end the subsequences here
    count += subseqs;
}
```

Now we just have to `return` the `count` after the loop has run.

Putting it all together, we get:

```java
static long solve(int[] ints) {
    var freq = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i : ints)
        freq.put(i, freq.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
    long count = 0;
    var grouped = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (var entry : freq.entrySet()) {
        if (grouped.contains(entry.getKey()))
            continue;
        int min = entry.getKey();
        while (freq.containsKey(min - 1))
            min--;
        int max = entry.getKey();
        while (freq.containsKey(max + 1))
            max++;
        long subseqs = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            grouped.add(i);
            // We can append any of the duplicate elements...
            subseqs *= freq.get(i);
            // Or we can just start a new subsequence with any of the duplicate elements.
            subseqs += freq.get(i);
            // We can end the subsequences here
            count += subseqs;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

for which we can write a simple test

```java
System.out.println(solve(new int[] {13, 11, 4, 12, 5, 4}));
System.out.println(solve(new int[] {3, 4, 4, 5, 6}));
```

which prints `11` and `16` respectively as expected.

---

If you're worried about the O(n) worst case performance of a hash map, there are other data structures you could use to provide O(1) access maps, for example storing the integers in a trie and leveraging that the integers have constant size. This results in linear size in the number of bits needed to encode the input, which a comparison-based sorting-based or tree-map-based approach does not achieve (this is similar to how radix sort compares to comparison based sorting).

Comment: `freq.put(i, freq.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);` can be simplified as `freq.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum)`.